# CSS table cell multiple background images overlap?

Tags: html, css

I cannot figure out how to move red & green blocks above the pink strip in the snippet below:

(garbage to ask question with more code
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba)

```css
.timeline {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 30px;
    width: 50px;
    position: relative;
}

.timeline span {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}

.timeline-node-red {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;

}

.timeline-node-green {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;

}

.timeline-node-white {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    display: inline-block;

}

.timeline .start {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
}

.timeline .start:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;

    right: -1px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 10px;
    top: 17px;
    background-color: #e88f9a;
}

.timeline .end {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
}

.timeline .end:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;

    width: 50%;
    height: 10px;
    top: 17px;
    background-color: #e88f9a;
}

.timeline.node:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;

    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    top: 17px;
    background-color: #e88f9a;
}

.timeline.node span,
.timeline.has-right span {
    display: inline-block;
}

table.timeline-table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    overflow: scroll;
}

table.timeline-table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

table.timeline-table tr th,
td {
    padding: 10px;
}

table.timeline tr td {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 30px;
    width: 50px;
    position: relative;
}


::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #f1f1f1;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #888;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: #555;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>


    <div style="width: 100%; overflow: scroll;">

    <table class="timeline-table">

        <tr style="color: white; background-color: #79b6f5;">
            <th style="min-width: 100px;">Driver</th>
            <th>08:00</th>
            <th>08:30</th>
            <th>09:00</th>
            <th>09:30</th>
            <th>10:00</th>
            <th>10:30</th>
            <th>11:00</th>
            <th>11:30</th>
            <th>12:00</th>
            <th>12:30</th>
            <th>13:00</th>
            <th>13:30</th>
        </tr>
        
        
        <tr>
            <td class="">Some Driver </td>
            <td class="timeline"></td>
            <td class="timeline"></td>
            <td class="timeline"><span class="start"></span>
            </td>
            <td class="timeline node"><span></span></td>
            <td class="timeline node"><span class="timeline-node-red" style="margin-left: 20px;">5</span></td>
            <td class="timeline node"><span></span></td>
            <td class="timeline node"><span></span>
            </td>
            <td class="timeline"><span class="end"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `z-index=1` in node-green & node-red css classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have applied hardcoded position top and left on many elements which is distorting your element, and also position and relative and absolute relation is also not properly made, I have done some fixes in position relative and absolute depending the td and span relation and changed the hard coded px into transform property for dynamic height and width of element.

```css
.timeline {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 30px;
    width: 50px;
    position: relative;
}

.timeline span {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
position: relative;
}

.timeline-node-red {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;

}

.timeline-node-green {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;

}

.timeline-node-white {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    display: inline-block;

}

.timeline .start {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.timeline .start:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: -100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    top: 50%;
    background-color: #e88f9a;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.timeline .end {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
}

.timeline .end:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: -100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    top: 50%;
    background-color: #e88f9a;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.timeline.node:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;

    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    top: 20px;
    background-color: #e88f9a;
}

.timeline.node span,
.timeline.has-right span {
    display: inline-block;
}

table.timeline-table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    overflow: scroll;
}

table.timeline-table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

table.timeline-table tr th,
td {
    padding: 10px;
}

table.timeline tr td {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 30px;
    width: 50px;
    position: relative;
}


::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #f1f1f1;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #888;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: #555;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>


    <div style="width: 100%; overflow: scroll;">

    <table class="timeline-table">

        <tr style="color: white; background-color: #79b6f5;">
            <th style="min-width: 100px;">Driver</th>
            <th>08:00</th>
            <th>08:30</th>
            <th>09:00</th>
            <th>09:30</th>
            <th>10:00</th>
            <th>10:30</th>
            <th>11:00</th>
            <th>11:30</th>
            <th>12:00</th>
            <th>12:30</th>
            <th>13:00</th>
            <th>13:30</th>
        </tr>
        
        
        <tr>
            <td class="">Some Driver </td>
            <td class="timeline"></td>
            <td class="timeline"></td>
            <td class="timeline"><span class="start"></span>
            </td>
            <td class="timeline node"><span></span></td>
            <td class="timeline node"><span class="timeline-node-red" style="margin-left: 20px;">5</span></td>
            <td class="timeline node"><span></span></td>
            <td class="timeline node"><span></span>
            </td>
            <td class="timeline"><span class="end"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```